# Build-in Intent to Pick an account

Tags: android, android-intent, accountmanager

Is there a build-in Intent I can use to let the user pick an account from the accountmanager or do I have to build the accountpicker activity myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API 14+ you can use the [#newChooseAccountIntent(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle%29) in the account manager. Before that it was all manual.

There was a "ChooseAccountActivity" at least as early as in 2.3 I believe, but this is an unpublished API - if you google it you should find the class though - it should be possible to use it if you're careful.

(Or just go and lift the code from [the SDK](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/accounts/) and put it in your own project)